# Writing a dynamically created bitmap to a panel (or any other control)

Tags: c#, asp.net, graphics

Right now I have the following code, which works fine to display my dynamically created image in the web page, but it overwrites whatever controls there were. How do I display the image inside a specific control, instead?

Ideally, I would like it to be displayed inside a panel (Panel1) that I have defined on my page.

```
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(W, H,  PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        //lots of drawing code

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            ms.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
        }

        bmp.Dispose();
        Response.End();
```

As I said, this works beautifully, except that it overwrites whatever controls I have on my page with the image, while I would like to constrain it to remain inside a panel.

is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: This post answered my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720929/is-there-anyway-to-display-dynamically-generated-bitmap-on-a-asp-image-control

Answer (score 2):

you need to an `image` control inside your panel, and the `ImageUrl` attribute of that, must be set to send its request to a new `page` or `handler`, and at that page, you need to write your `bitmap`, i have posted solution for this [...Here...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21753880/how-to-bind-image-gallery-with-sql-data-table-in-asp-net/21756344#21756344)

check that

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm still learning and your solution seems a little above my current abilities, but I will experiment with it and see how I fare.

Comment: I'm so sorry, but the actual implementation of this still eludes me. How do I "send the image" to a new page? I can create a newpage.aspx in my solution, and once I've created the graphics object g, how do I send it to the response.outputstrea, of newpage.aspx?

Answer (score 0):

assume you have a page named `PageA.aspx` containing a `panel`, you need an `image` element, inside the panel, like this:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" 
    runat="server" 
    CssClass="w120px h120px" 
    ImageUrl='newpage.aspx' />
```

notice to `ImageUrl` Attribute...

this image sends a request to `newpage.aspx` to get the picture...
in the `page_load` of `newpage.aspx` you need to write your `MemoryStream` which is containing your picture to the `Response` like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = "image/png";
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(W, H, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);

        //lots of drawing code

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bmp.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
        }

        bmp.Dispose();
        Response.End();
    }
```